# How to deal with libstdc++ throwing exception across execution boundaries

Tags: c++, exception

According to [THIS page](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/STR51-CPP.+Do+not+attempt+to+create+a+std%3A%3Astring+from+a+null+pointer),lots of the std::string functions can throw exceptions in libstdc++ implementation. I cannot change the implementation of libstdc++ and it would be too expensive to switch to other libraries. My current goal is to make my code which heavily uses std::string compliant with SEI CERT C++ Coding Standard. My questions are:

1. How to work around this issue such that libstdc++ does not throw across execution boundaries?
2. I think no matter which standard library implementation I switch to, I may still end up having this issue because throwing exceptions from a library is such a common and arguably reasonable thing to do. Then does it mean that I will always face such an issue? Is it just so trivial in practice so people don't really care much or it is just a trade off that people make to use exception to handle errors?

Thanks!

Comment: "execution boundary" is probably a term from the mentioned coding standard, but it's not one used regularly in the context of C++. Two more things come to mind: Yes, you can't escape exceptions under normal circumstances and while still writing idiomatic C++. However, if aborting is acceptable, you may be able to rebuild a std library that does that instead of throwing. I seem to remember that at least STLport used to have such an option.

Comment: What do you mean by _"execution boundaries"_ ? If you mean ABI boundaries then letting exceptions cross an ABI boundary is probably Undefined Behaviour (might be implementation defined - check your tool chain docs).

Comment: @RichardCritten: No, it isn't. There are plenty of ABI's that support exceptions, such as the Itanium ABI for C++.

Comment: @MSalters then the exception is not crossing an ABI boundary.

Comment: @RichardCritten: I don't find your "ABI boundary" more informative than the "execution boundary" from the question, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That C++ coding standard already forbids you from passing non-standard-layout types across execution boundaries, and `std::string` is such a type. The exception part doesn't make the problem worse.

The sane solution generally chosen is not to have "execution boundaries" in your program. Instead, you compile the whole program using a single ABI and using a single Standard Library.

If you have a plugin mechanism, you typically create a narrow API for that plugin interface. On this interface you might even stick to a C ABI, so the plugin author isn't restricted to C++. And since that's a C ABI, you make sure that your C++ exceptions aren't being thrown over to the plugin. `std::string` isn't an issue here, you work with `char const*`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "you compile the whole program using a single ABI and using a single Standard Library." could you please elaborate a little bit more on how to do this? Say my program forms one ABI and the Standard Library forms another ABI, then as long as I use those std::string functions in my program, exceptions will cross ABI boundaries, right? Did you mean that I need to compile the standard library source code together with my program source code? Thanks.

Comment: @james: The Standard Library by definition is part of your C++ implementation and must match the compiler. You don't need to compile it specifically,  that's already done for you. For completeness, note that on Linux the situation is slightly more messy because common implementations rely on the OS version of the C library. But that doesn't affect `std::string` or exceptions, of course.

Comment: Thanks @MSalters. I may have some misunderstanding of how the standard library work. Is that because std::string is implemented header-only such that once included, it becomes part of my implementation, which as you said, it's already done for me by the compiler. What about those functions that have pre-compiled into binary forms in libstdc++.so or libstdc++.a? When linking with libstdc++, if any of those functions throw, would that cause the exceptions to cross the ABI boundary? e.g. exceptions cross from libstdc++.so to myprog.exe?

Comment: @james: You appear to struggle with terminology. In C++ speak, "the implementation" refers to the preprocessor, compiler, linker, and Standard Library - basically the parts that are described by the C++ Standard. It very much is **not** your program. The implementation as a whole has to behave according to the Standard, and the Standard says that `std::string` works, and that exceptions work. The whole "ABI boundary" mess only really starts when you start mixing compilers, so it's unclear what "**the** implementation" means.

Comment: But is it possible to have the standard library compiled in one compiler and my own code compiled in a different machine using a different compiler? When a function in that standard library throws an exception, would that exception cross the ABI boundary?

Comment: @james: Probably another jargon thing. "The" standard library doesn't really exist. There's an abstract specification in the ISO C++ Standard, and multiple concrete implementations for multiple compilers. Now `libstdc++` is somewhat of a special case in that it can be used by GCC and Clang, but that is explicitly the case because those two use the same ABI. Microsoft OTOH uses a special "VC++ redistributable package" to make sure you get the right library on every machine.

Comment: Then even if I "compile the whole program using a single ABI and using a single Standard Library", I may still have the risk of exception crossing ABIs. For example, some version of the standard library throws an exception and my application which built using another version of the standard library try to catch it...

Comment: @james: You're clearly not so experienced that you're building complex programs with plugin architectures. Hence, you are in control about the one Standard Library used by your program, and that's the one suitable for your compiler.

Comment: Hi @MSalters, I'm not trying to invent meaningless use case. It's just that after I ran Coverity to enforce CERT coding standard, it flags this issue on a header (basic_string.h) of the standard library and hence I got this question. I understand that I have full control of which standard library to use to compile with my code but I may not have full control on where the code is run. For example, say my code was built with standard library version 1.0, and run in a machine which has standard library of version 2.0. The ABIs of my code and host machine's standard library may not be compatible.

Comment: @james: Effectively both Windows and Linux allow side-by-side installs for different ABI versions. Versions 1 and 2 can co-exist.